# Could not load an assembly from specific folder

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, relative-path

So here is my problem - 
I have an application "A" which uses a common dll "Login.dll". 
This common dll is placed inside a folder "CommonDll" . This dll is supposed to be accessed by many application. To do so i have put following code  in CONFIG of  Calling Application "A"

```
<runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="Login"  culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="105c4b5bbc9d3d16"/>
          <codeBase version="1.0.0.0" href="file:///C:/CommonDll/Login.dll"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
```

This is working perfectly fine on my local machine. However if i put the same folder structure on others machine and deploy this application, its giving me an error 
Could not load file or assembly 'Login, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=105c4b5bbc9d3d16' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

But on clients machine if i run this

```
file:///C:/CommonDll/Login.dll
```

This is targeting the correct dll .

Any suggestion or view is highly appreciated...

Comment: Have you considered using [GAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Did you already check the file properties of Login.dll? Maybe it is blocked on the target machine because it was copied from a (untrusted) network location.

Comment: Or maybe Login.dll have referencing other assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem shoul dbe solved if you use automatic assembly resolving. I like to use the following code:

```
var yourCommondDllFolder = new DirectoryInfo("C:/CommonDll/").GetFiles("*.dll");

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
{
    var dll = yourCommondDllFolder.FirstOrDefault(fi => fi.Name == args.Name);
    if (dll == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return Assembly.Load(dll.FullName);
};
```

Than your app domain try to resolve the assembly when it could not be loaded.