# Load assembly from folder and specific version

Tags: vb.net, dll-injection

In a VB.net solution I need to load some dll from a specific folder. I have read
[Could not load an assembly from specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26774521/could-not-load-an-assembly-from-specific-folder) and many others but in my case no luck. I have tried to add in app.config lines to reference to the file I need :

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Eplan.EplApi.Starteru" publicKeyToken="57aaa27e22f7b107" />
  <publisherPolicy apply="yes" />
  <codeBase version="1.0.0.0" href="C:\Program Files\EPLAN\Platform\2023.0.3\Bin\Eplan.EplApi.Starteru.dll"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

But when I try to start my solution I have a System.InvalidOperationException without any other message. I have also tried this solution https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53408.vb-net-dynamically-load-assemblies.aspx without luck.Any idea for solving?

Comment: If you want to dynamically load an assembly, check out the [Assembly class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly?view=net-7.0).
If you want the DLL to be a project dependency, add it via the "References" menu

Comment: The assemblies I need to use, in their manual said: "More precisely, you need to make sure to load the API assemblies from exactly this folder. The reason for this is, that the API assemblies have statically linked unmanaged dependencies, which need to be loaded directly from the current directory. " So, even if I reference them from Visual Studio, later in the exe file dosn't work.

Comment: I'm tring the solution on thecnet, but in visual studio 2022 seems dosn't work